# Access my files from the public directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

With the [upload_multiple](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-columns#upload_multiple-1) field / column, I need to open file with the existing link.

However when I open the link I get a 404.

This is how I do things :

```
        // setupCreateOperation

        CRUD::addField([
            'name'      => 'documents',
            'label'     => 'Documents',
            'type'      => 'upload_multiple',
            'upload'    => true,
        ]);

        // setupShowOperation

        CRUD::addColumn([
            'name'    => 'documents',
            'label'   => 'Documents',
            'type'    => 'upload_multiple',
        ]);

        // Model

        public function setDocumentsAttribute($value)
        {
            $attribute_name = "documents";
            $disk = "public";
            $destination_path = "documents";

            $this->uploadMultipleFilesToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
        }
```

So the documents are in storage > app > public > documents.

What appears in the form (show or edit) : http://localhost/documents/65004a2cdbd104406b025d14c6519ce9.pdf (404)

[image]

And I already exectuted `php artisan storage:link`

If you have any idea, that would be nice...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can show your route:

```
http://localhost/documents/65004a2cdbd104406b025d14c6519ce9.pdf (404)
```

when you work in localhost with Laravel, you need proporcionate complete url.

Your url to access this resource sould be:

```
assets('storage/documents/'.65004a2cdbd104406b025d14c6519ce9.pdf)
```

with this example, try generate link, should can show your documents.

Your problem it´s you need access to storage path.

Sorry for my bad english. I hope help you

Comment: Ty for your answer. Unfortunately I don't have access to where the link is displayed (as I use Laravel Backpack).

Comment: @Alteyss you can update your question with your actual code from controller or how you ´re trying return this link?

Comment: This is what I did with setupCreateOperation and setupShowOperation. Did you already use Backpack?

Comment: @Alteyss i never have used Backpack, but i can see that it´s other admin panel? it´s similar to adminLTE but this panel it´s installed with composer. this library contains, blades.. and you need to return data from your controller to this blades. I need how you´re doing return in your controller data to blade or how you are generating link for this

Comment: @Alteyss in your actual code, it´s for insert in your db? but you need return anything to create this link.